# Is there any diference between "!= NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there any difference between using "!= NULL" and using "IS NOT NULL"?

For example:

`SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE a_field IS NOT NULL`

and

`SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE a_field != NULL`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is. `!=` does not work properly with `NULL`<sup>1</sup>:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 != NULL, 1 IS NOT NULL;
+-----------+---------------+
| 1 != NULL | 1 IS NOT NULL |
+-----------+---------------+
|      NULL |             1 |
+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

BTW: `!=` is not valid SQL, you should use the diamond operator `<>`.

<sup>1</sup> In fact no comparison, except `IS` and `IS NOT` works.

Comment: `!=` (as well as `<>`) is valid in MySQL.  I guess other SQL implementations might not work with it.

Comment: "*`!=` is not valid SQL*". [It is in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal).

Comment: @h2ooooooo I have specifically written SQL and not MySQL.

Comment: The question is about MySQL specifically as far as I can see.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That's correct, but pointing towards the standard conform way cannot hurt either.

Comment: Alright, it doesn't hurt to follow the SQL spec as you've said. Though, most DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle) support both `<>` and `!=` operators. I personally prefer the `!=` which resembles the C-style syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't compare values to null, becouse efect of this operation isn't `true` neither `false` - it's  always `unknown`.

To check is value null, you should always use `is null`